# Amcharts 3D charts - category axis getting mixed with the value axis wrongly

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I am using amcharts with 3D (i.e. depth3D=40), the chart comes up good but the category axis is getting overlapped/merged with the value axis

I am using something like this :

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "startDuration": 1,   
  "valueAxes": [{
    "id": "v1",
    "title": "Cost (in USD)",
    "position": "left",
    "autoGridCount": false,
    "labelFunction": function(value) {
      return "$" + Math.round(value);
    }
  }, {
    "id": "v2",
    "title": "Effort ( hh:mm )",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "position": "right",
    "autoGridCount": false,
    "duration": "mm",
    "durationUnits": {
      "hh": "h ",
      "mm": "min"
     }
  }],

  ---------------------
  ---------------------

 "depth3D": 40,
 "angle": 10,    
  "chartCursor": {
    "pan": true,
    "cursorPosition": "mouse",
    "cursorAlpha": 0.1,
    "cursorColor": "#000000",
    "fullWidth": true,
    "valueLineAlpha": 0.2
  },
  "categoryField": "lob",
   "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "axisAlpha":0.9,
        "axisThickness": 1,                     
        "axisColor": "black",        
        "gridAlpha":0,
        "labelRotation":25,
        "fontSize":10,
        "boldLabels":true

    },
```

Here is my  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NawazSE/bsjdt85w/1/)

It's the value axis(in red color) getting merged/mixed with the category axis.

Any suggestions to avoid the axis merging/overlapping would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have 3D enabled using angle/depth3D, the chart perspective is shifted. The red line you're seeing is part of the value axis line that is extended into 3D space due to the new perspective, so it's by design; note that the other axis does this too if you set the angle in the opposite direction. As a result, there isn't a way to remove this using the config. As a hack, you can try editing the SVG directly through the `drawn` event by querying the [axis line by class/id](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/css-class-names/) with [`addClassNames`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#addClassNames) set to true and modifying the `d` attribute:

```
function remove3DSegment() {
  var line = document.querySelector('.value-axis-v2 .amcharts-axis-line');
  var lineSVG = line.getAttribute('d');
  line.setAttribute('d', lineSVG.substr(0, lineSVG.lastIndexOf(' '))); //last part of the SVG path command contains the 3D segment on the bottom
}

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "startDuration": 1,
  "addClassNames": true,
  // ...
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "drawn",
    "method": remove3DSegment
  }],
  // ...
});
```

If you want to generalize it, you can have the function look for the chart's id and value axis' id through the event.

```
function remove3DSegment(e) {
  var divId = e.chart.div.id;
  var valueAxisId = e.chart.valueAxes[1].id; //assumes your second axis is the one that needs to be modified.
  var line = document.querySelector('#' + divId + ' .value-axis-' + valueAxisId + ' .amcharts-axis-line');
  var lineSVG = line.getAttribute('d');
  line.setAttribute('d', lineSVG.substr(0, lineSVG.lastIndexOf(' '))); //last part of the SVG path command contains the 3D segment on the bottom
}
```

Note that this is a hack and if the SVG path command for drawing the axis gets changed in a future v3 release, then this may likely break.

```js
function remove3DSegment() {
  var line = document.querySelector('.value-axis-v2 .amcharts-axis-line');
  var lineSVG = line.getAttribute('d');
  line.setAttribute('d', lineSVG.substr(0, lineSVG.lastIndexOf(' ')));
}
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "startDuration": 1,
  "addClassNames": true,
  "valueAxes": [{
    "id": "v1",
    "title": "Cost (in USD)",
    "position": "left",
    "autoGridCount": false,
    "labelFunction": function(value) {
      return "$" + Math.round(value);
    }
  }, {
    "id": "v2",
    "title": "Effort ( hh:mm )",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "position": "right",
    "axisAlpha": 0.9,
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "axisColor": "red",
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "id": "g4",
    "valueAxis": "v1",
    "lineColor": "#3B7610",
    "fillColors": "#3B7610",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "type": "column",
    "title": "Cost saving per year",
    "valueField": "costSaving",
    "clustered": false,
    "columnWidth": 0.3,
    "topRadius": 1,
    // "legendValueText": "$[[value]]M",
    "balloonText": "[[title]]<br /><b style='font-size: 90%'>$[[value]]M</b>"
  }, {
    "id": "g1",
    "valueAxis": "v2",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bulletSize": 5,
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "lineColor": "#20acd4",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
    "title": "Effort saving per year",
    "topRadius": 0.95,
    "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
    "valueField": "effortSaving",
    "balloonText": "[[title]]<br /><b style='font-size: 90%'>[[value]]</b>"
  }],
  "depth3D": 40,
  "angle": 10,
  "chartCursor": {
    "pan": true,
    "cursorPosition": "mouse",
    "cursorAlpha": 0.1,
    "cursorColor": "#000000",
    "fullWidth": true,
    "valueLineAlpha": 0.2
  },
  "categoryField": "lob",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0.9,
    "axisThickness": 1,
    "axisColor": "black",
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "labelRotation": 25,
    "fontSize": 10,
    "boldLabels": true

  },
  "legend": {
    "horizontalGap": 5,
    "maxColumns": 30,
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "markerSize": 10,
    "leftMargin": 0,
    "valueText": ""
  },
  "balloon": {
    "borderThickness": 1,
    "shadowAlpha": 0
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "drawn",
    "method": remove3DSegment
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
    "lob": "abca",
    "effortSaving": 64140,
    "costSaving": 3600
  }, {
    "lob": "dfasdf",
    "effortSaving": 326724,
    "costSaving": 1875
  }, {
    "lob": "dfgsdfgt",
    "effortSaving": 36864,
    "costSaving": 1500,
  }, {
    "lob": "gfsdg",
    "effortSaving": 101808,
    "costSaving": 3614,
  }, {
    "lob": "fgfgf",
    "effortSaving": 13200,
    "costSaving": 6215,
  }, {
    "lob": "jytujty",
    "effortSaving": 111312,
    "costSaving": 3123,
  }, {
    "lob": "erqwr",
    "effortSaving": 5040,
    "costSaving": 1235,
  }]
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: As I am using 4 different graphs on the document, so document.querySelect() needs to be specific to that particular graph, Please suggest if I should modify '.value-axis-v2 .amcharts-axis-line'

Comment: `-v2` corresponds to the id of the right value axis as documented [here](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/css-class-names/). If you're using different ids in each chart, what you can do instead is modify the call to either take a parameter for the value axis id or inline the function for each specific chart and tweak the querySelector call accordingly. If you still need help, make a fiddle with 4 charts that roughly matches what your setup is.

Comment: I have tried to replicate a similar issue (charts with different ids 'chartdiv1', 'chartdiv2', 'chartdiv3', 'chartdiv4') https://jsfiddle.net/NawazSE/bsjdt85w/11/
Please adivse !

Comment: I updated my response with how to generalize the function and updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ahx5rm26/). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks it's working([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NawazSE/bsjdt85w/26/)), But if I add another chart to the document with id 'chartdiv0' - its breaking([breaking here](https://jsfiddle.net/NawazSE/bsjdt85w/36/))

Comment: Of course it breaks. The code assumes you're using two value axes. chartdiv0 doesn't have two value axes and isn't even 3D (angle is set to zero), so why even bother adding the callback to it? It's meant for charts that are affected by this extra line you're complaning about where the second value axis grid line is drawn toward the user in 3D space. chartdiv0 doesn't have this problem, so the drawn callback is not necessary. Only include the callback where it's needed. It's not meant to be a universal drop in function for *every single chart*, just a solution to this particular problem.

Comment: Oh! It was a typo mistake, I corrected it. Thanks a lot xorspark !